# String formatting lost from URL string capture when sending from client to node js back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, client-server

I'm trying to get a simple formatted string (as follows) to my node js back-end.

```
'one\ntwo\nthree'
```

Instead, when printing to console from node js I get:

```
'onetwothree'
```

I SHOULD get:

one

two

three

In fact, when I take the exact same printed console message and paste it in the Node js code to overwrite that from the client, it's printed correctly!..

My client code:

```
let content = '1\n2\n3';

fetch(`/api/post?textCapture=${content}`)
```

Server code:

```
app.get('/api/post', (req,res) => {

    let textCapture = req.query.textCapture;

    console.log("textCapture: " + textCapture);

}
```

Any ideas how I can resolve??

Thanks,

As above.

Also tried sending the string via the body of the Fetch from client, but I got a 404 not-found error.

### UPDATE:

Here's an interesting find looking at ASCII table with buffer reads from my strings...

the incorrect print gives:

```
k \n ls \n t \n
<Buffer 6b 5c 6e 6c 73 5c 6e 74 5c 6e>
```

When I write out / copy paste from the console print and overwrite the variable I get the following correct print in the console:

```
k
ls
t
<Buffer 6b 0a 6c 73 0a 74 0a>
```

In the incorrect version a '5c' equates to '' and the '6e' to 'n'.
In the correct version a '0a' indicates the joint '\n'

Why is this happening...?

Comment: Needs more info to replicate.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code from the client and server.

Comment: You need to encode content with special characters. ```fetch(`/api/post?textCapture=${encodeURIComponent(content)}`)```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar, but still no luck. Odd thing is I can get the incorrect print out from the console ('h\ny\nu\n') and overwrite the variable on the backend and I'll get the correct output! : f
g
h
e each on a new line!

Comment: I can't think of any other reason why the newlines would be lost.

Comment: If you're sending complex text it's probably a better idea to use POST rather than GET.

Comment: I did try using POST and I would get a 404 error.. I just can't believe a relatively trivial thing which I though might be common is proving difficult. It MUST be the string itself - whilst using 'typeof()' identifies it as a String, it certainly doesn't behave as such... I've proven typing it out / copying and pasting from console works! :(

Comment: @Barmar, found something that might interest / inform you as well as it did me...although I'm not any closer to a solution. See the update posted above regarding ASCII table lookup. Do you know why this might be happening? Thanks

Comment: Your incorret output has a literal backslash in it, that's `5c`. That wouldn't happen with `let content = '1\n2\n3';` but it would happen if you got the string some other way. Escape sequences are only processed in string literals, not in strings received as data (e.g. from input values, calls to `prompt()`, AJAX requests).

Comment: I get this from the Client / front-end with user input in a text-area so no way of avoiding having to send it to the backend over a fetch. Can you suggest an alternative?